# show some data on a map by OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, c#, visualisation, visual-studio

I am very new to Open Street Map. 
I have some data that need to be shown on a map by Open Street Map from C# VS2013. It can be WPF or windows forms.

The data is about some statistics results by location.

For example,

```
 location,  latitude, longitude, address, population, household, income of household, tax of household
```

The data was got from a database by running SQL query from C# code. 
The data volume may have 1 million rows. I need to do some aggregation so that they can be displayed on the map clearly. For example, aggregate all houshold (located in zip code 10080) information in a circle displayed on the map.

Moreover, I need to provide the following functions the on map so that the users can do:

(1) when zoom in to a location, more detailed data (from zip code to street level) will be shown.

(2) when zoom out, only the aggregated data was shown. For example, from street level to zip code level.

(3) users can get detailed data by selecting any location on the map as long as the location has data to show. For example, if a location in zip code = 10080 was selected, all household information in the selected location can be shown.

(4) users can hold control and click any location so that multiple locations household information can be show.

I have checked OSM wiki website and API, but I still have no idea how to add the data to a OSM map and edit the map to show it clearly.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour], where you will see that there should be only one question asked.  Although you have included no question marks to count it looks like you may be trying to ask five questions so can you use the [edit] button beneath your question to only ask one, please?

Comment: It is a design question. The numerical marks are only the requirements for the design application. Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this makes your question of the form "Here are my requirements, can you help me design my solution?", and that is not suitable for focussed Q&A where we look to see what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Question was also cross posted here: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/45698/show-large-volume-of-data-on-a-map-of-openstreetmap-by-c-vs2013 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32929453/show-large-volume-of-data-on-a-map-of-openstreetmap-by-c-sharp-vs2013